# Update temp table with results from WITH statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008 R2: I can't get my head around updating a temp table I have with results from a `WITH` statement.

The temp table, which will be my main table, let's call it `#main`, is simple enough and looks like this for its first line (There are going to be hundreds of product codes so I can't hard code the product code in the solution):

```
Product |  GapForGoodsinWH1  |  GapForGoodsinWH2
1000    |           NULL     |            NULL
```

The NULLS are there before I run my with `WITH` statement. The purpose of the `WITH` statement is to identify the longest period of time, in days, that goods have not been received into a certain warehouse (denoted as WH1 and WH2 in this example.

My `WITH` statement works fine if I idenfity the productcode and the Warehouse:

```
WITH GoodsIn AS (
    SELECT 
        Product,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GoodsInDate DESC) AS RN,
        GoodsInDate
    FROM GoodsIn
    WHERE 
    GoodsInDate >= @StartDate
    and GoodsInDate <= @EndDate
    --
    AND Product = 1000
    AND Warehouse = 'WH1'
)
SELECT
    A.Product,
    MAX(DATEDIFF(DD, A.GoodsInDate, B.GoodsInDate)) AS TimeMissing
FROM 
    GoodsIn A
LEFT JOIN 
    GoodsIn B ON A.RN = B.RN + 1
GROUP BY   
    A.Product
HAVING 
    MAX(DATEDIFF(DD, A.GoodsInDate, B.GoodsInDate)) >= @Missing
```

So the date parameters look over a certain period and the `@Missing` parameter is for the user to list products if they have been missing for X period of time (defined in the parameter).

All I want to do is export the `TimeMissing` value into my `#main` table by updating it on the `Product`.  In this example I would want to update `#main.GapForGoodsinWH1`, by matching the Product to `#main.product` and the `Warehouse` to `#main.GapForGoodsinWH1`.

Any ideas would be welcome, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the structure for GoodsIn table? can there be multiple records for same product in the table?

Comment: Hello Kai - Yes, there can be.  You will have `Product`,`Warehouse` and `GoodsInDate`.  There will also be quantities but i'm not really interested in that, it's gap analysis between `GoodsInDate`s so as long as there is some quantity on a date an entry will be created.  For example, Product 1000 can appear multiple times during the month of August where there is an entry for that product, and the table will contain the entries for both WH1 and WH2.  It is feasible you can have two deliveries on the same day but that doesn't bother me because they will just return a 0 in my CTE.

Comment: Can you clearify what value do you want in GapForGoodsinWH1 column.

Comment: E.g. if for product 1000 the earliest date was 2015-01-01 and the lastest entry for the same is 2015-06-01 do you want this difference in any given warehouse?

Comment: The `TimeMissing` value, so it's fine to hard code the `Warehouse` value in the update query (but not the `Product`).

Comment: Perhaps if I can illustrate to further assist what the `WITH` statement produces:  
Product Code |  TimeMissing
  1000             |        3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if this is the result that you want but let me know if there its different than what you want:

```
WITH GoodsIn AS(
    SELECT 
        Product,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Product, GoodsInDate DESC) AS RN,
        GoodsInDate,
        WareHouse
    FROM GoodsIn
    WHERE 
    GoodsInDate >= @StartDate
    AND GoodsInDate <= @EndDate
    AND Product = @ID -- specidied product
    AND WareHouse = @WareHouse -- specidied WareHouse
)

Update m set GapForGoodsinWH1 = TBL.TimeMissing
From #main m
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT
        A.Product,
        MAX(DATEDIFF(DD, A.GoodsInDate, B.GoodsInDate)) AS [TimeMissing]
    FROM 
    GoodsIn A
    LEFT JOIN 
    GoodsIn B ON A.Product = B.Product AND A.RN = B.RN + 1
    GROUP BY   
    Product
)TBL ON TBL.Product = m.Product
 WHERE TBL.TimeMissing >= @Missing
```

Comment: Can exclude the warehouse and product in where conditions as per your requirement.

Comment: Hello Kai - This is great, thanks very much and works!

Comment: If its a large table i presume the performance will be not so good.

Comment: If that's the case you can try temp table instead of CTE and index the Row_number column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lag` window function to find the previous shipment:

```
lag(GoodsInDate) over (
    partition by Product, Warehouse 
    order by GoodsInDate)
```

Then you can look up the maximum difference in dates per product per warehouse, and store it in `main`:

```
; with  GoodsInWithDelta as
        (
        select  Product
        ,       GoodsInDate
        ,       lag(GoodsInDate) over (
                    partition by Product
                    order by GoodsInDate) as PrevDate
        from    GoodsIn
        where   Warehouse = 'WH1'
        )
,       MaxDeltaByProduct as
        (
        select  Product
        ,       max(datediff(day, PrevDate, GoodsInDate)) as MaxDelta
        from    GoodsInWithDelta
        group by
                Product
        )
update  m
set     GapForGoodsinWH1 = MaxDelta
from    main m
left join
        MaxDeltaByProduct mdbp
on      m.Product = mdbp.Product
```

[Example at SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ea1d2/1/0)  You can repeat this query for the second warehouse.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
WITH GoodsIn AS (
    SELECT 
        Product,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GoodsInDate DESC) AS RN,
        GoodsIn
    FROM GoodsIn
    WHERE 
    GoodsIn >= @StartDate
    and GoodsIn <= @EndDate
    --
    AND Product = 1000
    AND Warehouse = 'WH1'
)
Update m set GapForGoodsinWH1 = g.TimeMissing
From #main m
Inner Join (
    SELECT
        A.Product,
        MAX(DATEDIFF(DD, A.GoodsInDate, B.GoodsInDate)) AS TimeMissing
    FROM GoodsIn A
    LEFT JOIN GoodsIn B
        ON A.RN = B.RN + 1
    GROUP BY   A.Product
    HAVING MAX(DATEDIFF(DD, A.GoodsInDate, B.GoodsInDate)) >= @Missing
) as g 
    on g.product = m.product
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... Forgive me if I'm being dense but I don't get where you are defining A.RN and B.RN in your solution?

Comment: The `with` query in the question does not assign row numbers per product or per warehouse. Your `left join` doesn't use product or warehouse as a condition either. The result should be rather random.